# Using a "noise eating" active low-pass filter

Tags: dc, low-pass, active-filter

I'm trying to use a MAX281 low-pass IC to filter a DC signal I'm producing on-board. I'm yet to find other chips with the same features so, if you haven't come across them, they're designed to work by writing feedback onto your signal through a capacitor. The reason I was attracted to them is that they a) eliminate DC offset errors normally associated with an active design and b) allow me to work with high (150V) DC voltages.

My circuit copies the diagram below, taken from the device datasheet:

[image: Circuit diagram]

The idea is that pin 7 samples the signal via an internal switched capacitor network (hence the clock) and the device writes feedback onto the signal through the capacitor on pin 1. 
The only difference in my design is that I don't use an external clock, I instead put a capacitor on pin 5 to use the internal oscillator instead.

However, instead of a filtered output, I find that the chip oscillates. The osc. trace below shows the "DC output" which should be filtered. The other, square-like trace is the output on pin 1 which, when put through the capacitor, causes the shape you see on the output. The clock rate is visible as the little steps in the output level.

[image: Oscillation of output]

Anyone have any tips / experience with these devices / useful google search terms? A rather basic block diagram of the devices is reproduced below:

[image: MAX281 block diagram]

A link to the datasheet: https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX281.pdf

Comment: What is your input signal? Can you provide a trace of it? Consider including a link to the datasheet. Chances are there is some attribute of the input signal that is out of range.

Comment: Hi Squats, thanks for the comment. I'll add a link to the datasheet to the question. The input signal is a boring DC voltage in the range of -150V to +150V (the behavior shown above occurs all over this range). I haven't properly analysed the noise, but it looks ~10mV p2p with no visually obvious frequency components.

Comment: This is all a little unclear so I think nobody can take a stab at answering it. Could you refine *what* the -150 to +150v DC is? Sure it is a DC voltage, but from what? How much ripple does it have that you are trying to eliminate? Are you sure the + and -5v being supplied to the MAX281 are clean? Is there a capacitance or load limit you are exceeding elsewhere?

Comment: SwitchedCap filters are noise producing filters.They are badbeetles

Comment: @rdtsc The DC voltage comes from a high voltage opamp which is amplifying a 10V DAV. The +-5V rails are pretty clean: I haven't got the spectrum analyser out but they look good on the scope. Your last point is a good one, but I think I'm clear of all component ratings.

Comment: @Autistic I've heard this, but thought I'd give them a try just to see. But these guys aren't just adding noise, they're butchering the signal completely! There's definitely something wrong with the setup.

Comment: why can't a standard decoupling structure (using capacitors to ground) be used? If you know roughly what frequencies you want to remove you can pick capacitors for the main ones - just be sure their own self-resonance isn't at one of the frequencies you want to remove.

Comment: You can design your own filter that works like this ( no dc connection) with normal continuous time op amps. Sorry I can’t give you the reference, perhaps you can find it with Google. I used such a circuit 40 years ago. Here you go: google “zero offset active filter”